# how to have flat list render only once?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I am trying to print the ComponentTwo Flatlist only once but instead, I am getting the result [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjNWV.png) but instead, I need it to appear like this [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xugF.png). I have attached a snack link with the code in it.

Code That will produce the same results as in the images
[Expo Snack Link](https://snack.expo.io/@sal10/app)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve]. You must add your code to the question - not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/app)

[image]

Here is how you can fix this, first pass the `index` value to `ComponentOne` from `App.js`

```
const App = () => {
 return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
            data={DATA}
            renderItem={({item, index}) => <ComponentOne name={item.title} index={index}/>}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Now use that prop value to render `ComponentTwo` conditionally in `ComponentOne` like shown below:

```
//...const 

ComponentOne = (props: ComponentOneProps) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ margin: 15, backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}>
      <FlatList
        data={recent}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          console.log("hello")
          // @ts-ignore
          return props.index == 0?<ComponentTwo name={item.name} />:null;
        }}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.idd}
      />
//...
```